# AWS: execute script when deploying Application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to use EB CLI to deploy my PHP Application to AWS ElasticBeanstalk but I am wondering if there is a way to execute additional commands, for example download dependencies and compile files, etc.

Do I need to create a script? If yes how can I do it?

Any documentation is very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You need to read the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Answer (score 0):

In general, the idea of beanstalk is that you do all the downloading of dependencies etc yourself (ideally in a CI pipeline), create a deployable package and then hand it over to beanstalk for deployment and execution.

You may want to look into [AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/) for running scripts, building and packaging before deploying to beanstalk.

Comment: The problem is, I am developing in Mac and the instance is Linux, some libraries are different when compiling